# Location of "directory containing symbolic versions of my app's shared libraries" (ndk-stack)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Actually, my application is crashing with

> SIGNAL 11 error

after using some native libraries.

To track down this, i want to use the `ndk-stack`. But can't find the

> directory containing symbolic versions of my app's shared libraries!

I'm using eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

No idea where eclipse puts things, but ndk-build will generate an `obj` directory next to your `jni` directory. `-syms` should point at `obj/local/$ABI/`.